# Run a single test with gradle, kotest, and Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform, kotest

In [kotest-examples-multiplatform](https://github.com/kotest/kotest-examples-multiplatform) I can run a single test from the `commonTest` module with the command:

```sh
gradle :jvmTest --tests DataDrivenTest
```

I've created a new project in https://kmp.jetbrains.com only for iOS and Android development. I've added kotest to the project:

```sh
//libs.versions.toml

kotest = "5.8.0"
[libraries]
kotest-assertions-core = { module = "io.kotest:kotest-assertions-core", version.ref = "kotest" }
kotest-framework-engine = { module = "io.kotest:kotest-framework-engine", version.ref = "kotest" }
[plugins]
kotestMultiplatform = { id = "io.kotest.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotest" }
```

```kts
//main build.gradle.kts
alias(libs.plugins.kotestMultiplatform) apply false

//:shared build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotestMultiplatform)
}
sourceSets {
    commonMain.dependencies {
        // put your Multiplatform dependencies here
    }
    
    commonTest.dependencies {
        implementation(libs.kotest.assertions.core)
        implementation(libs.kotest.framework.engine)
        implementation(kotlin("test"))
    }
}
```

I've also added two tests in separate files in the `:shared:commonTest` module:

```kotlin
class FailTest : StringSpec({

    "fail test" {
        true shouldBe false
    }
})

class SuccessTest : StringSpec({

    "success test" {
        true shouldBe true
    }
})
```

and with the command:

```sh
gradle check
```

I can run those tests correctly but I can't figure out how to run tests only in a specific class. During development, I'd like to run the test with a single target like `android (local)` or `iosSimulatorArm64`. And if I could execute a specific test separately like mentioned here [conditional-tests-with-gradle](https://kotest.io/docs/framework/conditional/conditional-tests-with-gradle.html) it would be pretty awesome.